# Is There a good ASP.NET membership provider for Postgre SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have decided to use postgre instead of sql server. My only problem is that I need a Membership provider for postgre. Are there any good ones out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

[Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for Postgresql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/)

Bye

Comment: That's not a membership provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try dotConnect for PostgreSQL:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/editions.html